# Google JavaScript closure: defining a structure passed to many functions

Tags: javascript, types, google-closure-compiler

As I'm strengthening my JavaScript code using the Google closure compiler, I ran in a problem for which I don't see an answer I like.

I have a simple class with 4 functions as such:

```
open:  function(settings) { ... },
close: function(settings) { ... },
hide:  function(settings) { ... },
show:  function(settings) { ... }
```

As you can see all the functions take in an object named settings. I can easily declare the settings with a strong typing definition such as:

```
/**
 * @param {{p1: string, p2: number, p3: function(string)}} settings The settings.
 */
open: function(settings) { ... };
```

This works, only I need to copy/paste the @param definition for each one of the open, close, hide, and show functions. So if I add a parameter, I'm to make sure that I update all 4 functions!

Is there a way to declare a type and then reuse it multiple times, without having to declare an actual JavaScript object? Something like this maybe?

```
/**
 * @deftype {{...}} some_name
 */
```

Or would you do that as an external definition so at least the execution environment doesn't see that definition?

P.S. the object in question never saves the settings. It uses that *structure* to hold data it generates (such as an identifier) and to know what the user wants the different functions to do. Each caller can have a different set of settings and the object itself can still act like a singleton (I need only one instance of the object to manage any number of *windows*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`@typedef`](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tags):

```
/**
 * @typedef {{p1: string, ...}}
 */
var Settings;
```

and later:

```
/**
 * @param {Settings} settings The settings.
 */
open: function(settings) { ... };
```

Comment: So I suppose that this `var Settings;` definition should be in an external .js file? Because I'm not too sure where it would otherwise fit in my code!

Comment: It depends. If you namespace your code (using `goog.provide`), you can use `my.name.space.Settings;` instead of `var Settings;`, in the file where the namespace is created.

Comment: Well... it seems to me that if defined in the namespace (I have one indeed) then it is going to be present in the object at runtime even though it is not a variable of the object, it's "external" to it.

Comment: Only writing `my.name.space.Settings;` won't create a property `Settings`, since you are not *assigning* to the property. Technically you are trying to *access* the property `Setting`, which does not exist. I also believe that the closure compiler removes typedefs from the source, but that might depend on the compilation level.

Comment: Hi, I think you need to provide `my.name.Settings` before making it a package level type hence, it shouldn't be `undefined`. Here your example has a  `private` definition which here seems to be `undefined`. Any thoughts?